# How to pass argument programmatically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

This is my code,

```
var baseurl = "https://localhost:8888/files/";

var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); 
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"#");
aTag.setAttribute('onclick',"getFolderList(" + baseurl + ")"); 
aTag.innerHTML = "Home /";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

Here, getFolderList is the JavaScript function which accepts one parameter. I used the above code, but it does not call the function. How to pass the "baseurl" value to the getFolderList function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to include quotes:

```
aTag.setAttribute('onclick',"getFolderList('" + baseurl + "')");
                                           ^               ^
```

The way you have written it, the engine will treat `https://localhost:8888/files/` as the variable name, which of course would cause a syntax error.

Finally, you should avoid writing code like this inside HTML attributes - it could lead to script injection attacks if `baseurl` comes from an external source. Use the event listener syntax instead:

```
aTag.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getFolderList(baseurl);
});
```

Comment: You have my +1 after the edit. IMO the second part of the answer should really be first.

Comment: Actually it's more a syntax error than a variable name :-)

Comment: @Bergi Good point - updated. Jon, agreed! But felt it important to actually answer the question as well as highlight the issues with it.